# Does Solaris have a problem with popen?

Tags: linux, makefile, solaris, popen

Please have a look on this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE *process_fp = popen("make -f -", "w");
    if (process_fp == NULL) {
        printf("[ERR] make not found!\n");
    } else {
        char txt[1024] = "all:\n\t@echo Hello World!\n";
        fwrite(txt, sizeof(char), strlen(txt), process_fp);
        pclose(process_fp);
    }
}
```

This program will print "Hello World!". It works on the Linux platform, but failed on [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29), where it complains: `make: *** fopen (temporary file): No such file or directory.  Stop.`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just a related note, it is rare to find a bug in OS or compiler.So it would always help when you start with the mindset that there must be some issue in the code one writes. Remember "Select isn't broken" (Tip from "The Pragmatic Programmer"). Also see:http://www.travisswicegood.com/index.php/2009/01/04/select-isn-t-broken

Comment: For me, (opensolaris 2008.11 on x86) this works just as well as on Linux

Comment: Works for me on Solaris 10 on SPARC as well, though the compiler correctly points out you forgot the #include <string.h> for strlen().

What version of Solaris are you hitting the problem on?
What version of make is being found in your $PATH? (Solaris make or GNU make)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run `make -f -` manually; it probably doesn't work on Solaris. Try `gmake` (for GNU make) instead.

Comment: another thing worth trying might be to do "truss ./a.out" to trace the system calls to see what the actual failing fopen call is.